# Using Gson to display map of enums with their properties

Tags: java, enums, gson

I am using Gson and I want to serialize and display an enum.

My enum:

```
Tuple{

    SINGLE(1,"Single"), 
    DOUBLE(2,"Double")

    Tuple(int asInt,String properName){
        this.asInt=asInt;
        this.fullName=fullName;
    }

    public int AsInt;
    public String fullname;
}
```

I'd like to have output like this:

```
(SINGLE:{asInt:1,fullName:'Single'},DOUBLE:{asInt:2,fullname:'Double'})
```

How can I go about making this?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, it seems you need some custom serialization and deserialization. Check [this](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization) link. It has a pretty self-descriptive example you can use as a kickstart.

Comment: I need to go a little farther than custom deserialization.  I need to have a map of values instead of the default of having an array.

Comment: A map with SINGLE and DOUBLE as keys and the attributes as value or with the asInt as key and the fullName as value?

Comment: With SINGLE and DOUBLE as the keys.